# Cambiar el estilo de una fila en una tabla html

Tags: html, angular

Soy un poco nuevo en esto de angular y html asi que no se del todo cuales son las mejores maneras de hacer ciertas cosas. En concreto quiero que al hacer click sobre una fila de una tabla, la fila cambie de estilo. Hasta el momento solo he visto dos opciones o bien hacer dos divs en el html

```
    <table cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <th width="5%"></th>
        <th width="25%">CÓDIGO</th>
        <th width="30%">DESCRIPCIÓN</th>
        <th width="10%">CANT.</th>
        <th width="10%">PRECIO</th>
        <th width="10%">DTO.(%)</th>
        <th width="10%">IMPORTE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let venta of ventas; let i = index">
        <div *ngIf="selectedRow == i" class="selectedRow">
            <td (click)="cambiarSelecion(i)"></td>
            <td (click)="cambiarSelecion(i)">{{venta.id}}</td>
            <td (click)="cambiarSelecion(i)">{{venta.description}}</td>

            <td (click)="modificarCantidad(valorCelda, i, true)">
                <div *ngIf="rowEdit == i">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="valorCelda" (blur)="modificarCantidad(valorCelda, i, false)">
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="rowEdit != i">
                    {{venta.qty}}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{formateaValor(venta.price)}}</td>
            <td>{{formateaValor(venta.discount)}}</td>
            <td>{{formateaValor(venta.qty*venta.price*(1 - venta.discount/100))}}</td>
        </div>
        
        <div *ngIf="selectedRow != i">
            <td (click)="cambiarSelecion(i)"></td>
            <td (click)="cambiarSelecion(i)">{{venta.id}}</td>
            <td (click)="cambiarSelecion(i)">{{venta.description}}</td>

            <td (click)="modificarCantidad(valorCelda, i, true)">
                <div *ngIf="rowEdit == i">
                    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="valorCelda" (blur)="modificarCantidad(valorCelda, i, false)">
                </div>
                <div *ngIf="rowEdit != i">
                    {{venta.qty}}
                </div>
            </td>
            <td>{{formateaValor(venta.price)}}</td>
            <td>{{formateaValor(venta.discount)}}</td>
            <td>{{formateaValor(venta.qty*venta.price*(1 - venta.discount/100))}}</td>
        </div>
    </tr>
</table>
```

O bien poner el estilo en el archivo de angular y hacer una función que cambie el style usando el atributo [ngStyle]. Ambas opciones me desagradan bastante puesto que tengo ya un documento muy largo de html (porfavor notad que esta es solo una parte del html) y copiar y pegar el mismo div dos veces hace que aún sea más ilegible todo el código y más de lo mismo en el archivo de angular.
He estado pensando y se me ha ocurrido que si de alguna manera pudiera juntar el *ngIf con el [ngStyle] podria escoger el estilo, pero no he encontrado mucho en internet. Cualquier otro metódo alternativo sera bien recibido.

Muchas gracias por adelantado

PD: selectedRow es la variable (de tipo number) que guarda la fila selecionada de articulos que es un array, cambiarSeleccion cambia el valor de selectedRow al pasado por parametro.

Comment: Te recomiendo este [blog](https://guru99.es/angular-table/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No debería ser tan dificil si usas algo así:

```
<div [ngClass]="selectedRow == i ? 'selectedRow' : ''">
```

Debería funcionar perfectamente, en teoría si la variable **selectedRow** es igual al **index** que en este caso es **i** debería aparecer la clase **selectedRow** por supuesto depende de la programación de la función que tienes llamada **cambiarSelecion(i)**

Espero haberte ayudado.